# API $http delete returns 405 when calling from factory in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise, http-delete

This is what I have in my factory. This was working fine when I was running it in regular ajax syntax from the controller.

```
function endAgentSession(sessionData, tokenData) {

            var sessionId = sessionData.data.sessionId,
                access_token = tokenData.access_token,
                baseURI = tokenData.resource_server_base_uri,
                endAgentSessionPayload = {
                    'sessionId': sessionId,
                    'forceLogOff': true,
                    'endContacts': true,
                    'ignorePersonalQueue': false
                    };

            console.log(sessionId, "sessID");


            return $http({
                'url': baseURI + 'services/v6.0/agent-sessions/' + sessionId,
                'type': 'DELETE',
                'headers': {
                    //Use access_token previously retrieved from inContact token service
                    'Authorization': 'bearer ' + access_token,
                    'content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                'data': endAgentSessionPayload
            }).then(function(res){
               return res })};
        }
```

This is my controller. When I call the endAgentSession function from the controller with an ng-click, it errors out to a 405..

```
 $scope.endAgentSession = function(){
    agentFactory.endAgentSession($scope.sessionData, $scope.tokenData);
};
```

What am I doing wrong? It was working w/ ajax in the controller, then seemed to break when I moved it to the factory and used a promise.

it's actually showing it' requesting a GET request in Network.. 
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

full controller:

```
csMgmtApp.controller('launchedController', ['$scope', '$http', '$document', '$resource', 'agentFactory', '$timeout', function ($scope, $http, $document, $resource, agentFactory, $timeout) {

$scope.agentStatePayload = {};
$scope.sessionData = {};
$scope.tokenData = {};
$scope.startSessionPayload = {
    'stationPhoneNumber': '2223222222',
    'inactivityTimeout': 0,
    'inactivityForceLogout': 'false'
};

$document.ready(function () {
    $scope.tokenData = agentFactory.getToken();
    console.log($scope.tokenData);
});

agentFactory.startSession($scope.startSessionPayload, $scope.tokenData).then(function(res){
    console.log("sessionId", res);
    $scope.sessionData = res;
});



$scope.endAgentSession = function(){
    agentFactory.endAgentSession($scope.sessionData, $scope.tokenData);
};


}]);
```

It all seems to be working, except for the endSession, now..

Comment: Have a look in the *Network* console at the two different requests (when in controller and when in factory), paying particular attention to the **Request Headers** section

Comment: I noticed the payload was passing through in the controller. Is there something specific I should keep an eye out for?

Comment: Not sure what *"the payload was passing through"* actually means. Simply look at how the requests differ (you need only look at the *Headers* tab if Chrome, not sure about other browsers)

Comment: Are you sure you're API handles a payload with `DELETE`? Typically, a `DELETE` request doesn't contain any data

Comment: yeah, that's what it's saying in the docs under the JS for session end: https://developer.incontact.com/API/AgentAPI#!/Sessions/endSession

Comment: Maybe show the code (in the controller) that does work

Comment: No, I meant the controller code **that worked**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have guessed that every time you said

> regular ajax syntax from the controller

you meant you were using jQuery `$.ajax` previously.

The difference is that the property that sets the request method in Angular's `$http` is `method`, not `type`.

You can simplify it further using

```
return $http.delete(baseURI + 'services/v6.0/agent-sessions/' + sessionId, {
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + access_token,
    },
    data: endAgentSessionPayload
});
```

Comment: yeah.. poor description on my part (growing pains, i'll get there.. ) . Thank you for pointing out the mistake!

Comment: @someoneHere you might be interested in using `$resource` instead of `$http` for these RESTful API services